# variable not passing value outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm working on a Google Map Geocoding and I wonder why does my script won't carry the value of `g_lat` and `g_long` on that alert? I'm sure it has a value since when I do a `console.log()` it shows something.

```
var g_lat;
var g_long;

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    g_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    g_long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    console.log(g_lat); // output: -33.8468085
    console.log(g_long); // output: 151.06454640000004
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
alert(g_lat); // output: undefined
alert(g_long); // output: undefined
```

Comment: because the geocode function is asynchronous....

Comment: thanks Arun, however I'm quite naive in JS, what does this mean?

Comment: answer in the duplicate is not well explained -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leandro, it looks like you might need to start identifying which areas of your code you can push into individual functions. This will make it easier to achieve what you want to do.

First, however, callbacks. You know that you can pass functions as parameters into other functions right? This is an extremely useful feature, particularly when you're dealing with asynchronous calls to APIs. Something like this example - we call `doThis` but pass in a function to call once we've executed all the other things in `doThis` that we need to. The console will show the logs in order.

```
// `doThis` receives a function as a callback and executes it after doing stuff.
function doThis(callback) {
  console.log('logged first');
  callback();
}

// pass in a function as a parameter to `doThis` when we call it
doThis(function () {
  console.log('logged second');
});
```

Well, we can do that with your code too. (I've removed some of your code for brevity)

Push the geocode code into its own function. Here I'm pushing the results from the geocode into the callback:

```
function getGeocode(callback) {
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      callback(results);
    }
  });
}
```

Then call that function from somewhere else in your code using a callback. Here, the callback receives the results data from the geocode function.

```
getGeocode(function (results) {
  var g_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  var g_long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  console.log(g_lat, g_long);
});
```

You can even wrap this in it's own function so that anytime you want to grab some geocode data and log it (for example), you just need to execute it, perhaps by passing in the address you want:

```
function getGeocode(address, callback) {
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      callback(results);
    }
  });
}

function getGeocodeAndProcess(address) {
  getGeocode(address, function (results) {
    var g_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var g_long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    console.log(g_lat, g_long);
  });
}

getGeocodeAndProcess('chicago');
```

I hope this was useful to you.

Comment: Huge thanks for the explanation Andy. It works now thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the asynchronous nature of the request

```
var g_lat;
var g_long;

//this sends an asynchronous request, meaning the execution of next statements will continue without waiting for the response to the request
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
}, function (results, status) {
    //once the request is completed this method gets called, all code that depends on the value returned by this request should be kept here
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        g_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        g_long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(g_lat); // output: -33.8468085
        console.log(g_long); // output: 151.06454640000004
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
//thest statements are executed before the response comes back so you are getting undefined
alert(g_lat); // output: undefined
alert(g_long); // output: undefined
```

Comment: I'm out of idea, what should be the proper thing that I should do?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia the alerts should be within the callback method.... where are you using the `g_lat` & `g_long` values

Comment: No, it will work that way, but still I can't use it. alert() there is just for me to know if it does contains something,

Comment: @LeandroGarcia that is the only feasible solution... to move all codes that depends on those variable to be executed within the callback function... if you can share more details about what really you want to do then we can have another look at the problem

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't test it but it should do the trick, let me know.

```
var g_lat;
var g_long;


geocoder.geocode({'address': address}.then
    (function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            g_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            g_long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            console.log(g_lat); 
            console.log(g_long);
        }
    }),function(error) {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: that then() sesems to be new in me, what does it do?

Comment: This code won't work. 1) because `then` doesn't work like that, and 2) if you wanted to use `then` you would need to use a deferred object which this code doesn't.

Comment: Then works as a callback, do geocode then when get the call back from it do the function. I can't see problem. For exemple:myWebService.get("http://www.example.com")
    .then(function(result) { 
        return myDb.add(result); 
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('data successfully saved');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('an error occurred while saving:');
        console.dir(error);
    }); Font [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx