# Combining geocoding and Google directions

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geocoding

I am a PHP developer with little to no knowlegde of javascript, but I'm trying to combine geocoding and the google directions javascript code. Geocoding with PHP isn't an option because of the server side limit. This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
  initialize(); 
});


var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "hoefslag 41, 's gravenmoer";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            } 

    }); 




  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.764696,5.526042);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map, 
      title:"My location"
    }); 
  }





  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("routeStart").value;
    var end = "51.764696,5.526042";
    var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }




</script>


----- HTML for the map:

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:710px; height:300px"></div>   
    <form action="" onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
        <input type="text" id="routeStart" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Route plannen">
    </form>
<div id="directionsPanel"></div>
```

The latitude and longitude are calculated correctly from the address I've entered (checked by displaying the two variables. However, no matter what I try, I cannot seem to incorporate these two variables inside the two functions beneath the geocoding code, without breaking down the 'calculate route' functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: Without breaking means?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272785/variable-not-passing-value-outside-function/21273366

Comment: Well, I can get the variables in the first function after the geocoding so the right adress is displayed on the map, but whenever I do that, I'm unable the calculate a route. The buttons doesn't respond and doesn't seem the execute the function.

Comment: From where calcRoute() function being called up? Can you update with HTML code?

Comment: @JensonMJohn, sure done!

Comment: @user2704687 Checking.

Comment: @user2704687 Please Check whether this is fine. http://jenson.in/scriptarea.php

Comment: @JensonMJohn, yes! That seems to be it.

Comment: @user2704687 Lemme know if there are any errors else You can accept the answer if It's really worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try with this.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Map Address</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
     // initialize(); 
    });


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "hoefslag 41, 's gravenmoer";

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        alert("lat.."+latitude+"..&.."+longitude);
        initialize(latitude,longitude);
        $("#latlong").val(latitude+","+longitude);
                } 

        }); 




      var directionDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      function initialize(latitude,longitude) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng, 
          map: map, 
          title:"My location"
        }); 
      }





      function calcRoute() {

        var start = document.getElementById("routeStart").value;
        var end = $("#latlong").val();

        var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
        alert("Start.."+start+"..End.."+end);
      }




</script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Google Map Address</h2>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:710px; height:300px"></div>   
    <!--<form action="" onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">-->
    <form action="" id="routeForm">
        <input type="text" id="routeStart" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Route plannen" onClick="calcRoute();">
        <input type="hidden" name="latlong" id="latlong"/>
    </form>
   <div id="directionsPanel"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Jenson, I'm not sure you understood my problem. In the intialize function and in the calcroute function are two coordinates. The geocoding function must calculate these coordinates and the result of the geocoding function should be incorporated in the bottom  two functions.

Comment: @user2704687 coordinates you meant latitude & longitude?

Comment: Yes, the '51.764696,5.526042' has to be replaced by the result of the geocoding function. The address is entered in the geocoding function, that function calculates the latitude and longitude, those two numbers are incorporated in the two lower functions. That's the idea.

Comment: Thanks, let me check.

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm!! Thanks a lot for the extensive help!